# Find the distance between the two closest elements in an array of numbers

Tags: arrays

com forum,

I'm trying to compile this algorithm below in C++. Any ideas please?

```
// Find the distance between the two closest elements in an array of numbers.
// Minimum Distance
// dmin = infinity;
// for i = (i to n - 2) do
// for j = i + 1 to n - 1 do
// temp = A[i] - A[j]
// if temp < dmin;
// dmin = temp;
// return dmin;
```

Comment: This is not a homework-solving site. Do you have an actual problem that you're struggling with instead of "I have no idea whatsoever"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use that algorithm (`O(n^2)`), but rather sort the numbers, then do a linear scan (`O(nlogn)`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, phant0m is correct, but the sorting algorithm will itself use cycles.

Sorting algorithms are usually judged by their efficiency. In this case, efficiency refers to the algorithmic efficiency as the size of the input grows large and is generally based on the number of elements to sort. Most of the algorithms in use have an algorithmic efficiency of either O(n^2) or O(n*log(n)). (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sortcomp.html)

Unless the array is somewhat ordered already or you will later need the sorted version, or your array can get really really big, you might as well "bite the bullet" and stick with your original approach.